# Intuitive approach towards the auxiliary function of Lagrange's mean value theorem proof

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, differential-geometry, rolles-theorem

I have often seen many people using another auxiliary function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\cdot x$ where $f(x)$ is our original function continuous in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $g(x)$ satisfies all the condition of Rolle's theorem, to prove Lagrange's mean value theorem.
What is the intuition or methodology to arrive at that function $g(x)$?

Comment: In order to apply Rolle's theorem, you need a differentiable function $g$ on $[c,d]$ such that $g(c)=g(d)$ and then you can conclude that $g'(\xi)=0$. If you want to prove Lagrange's theorem you need somehow to adjust your function $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. What if you try to consider $g(x)=f(x)-kx$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: So its purely intuitive to reach to that equation.  Isn't there a more mathematical way?

Comment: As for me, it's the simplest way. You can consider instead $g(x)=f(x)+h(x)$ and then you need to choose $h$ in such a way that the condition $f(a)+h(a)=f(b)+h(b)$ holds. When searching some functions with certain properties it's reasonable to start with the simplest ones, e. g. polynomials or even constants and linear functions. However, constant functions doesn't satisfy required condition (unless $f(a)=f(b)$ already), so we move to the linear and they are indeed giving what we need.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the auxiliary function is
$$g(x)=f(x)-\left(\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\cdot (x-a)+f(a)\right)$$
which is the subtraction of the original function $f(x)$ and the function related to the secant line through the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$. In this way,
$g(a)=g(b)=0$ and we may apply Rolle's theorem.

The same works if we replace $g(x)$ with $h(x)=g(x)+c$ for **any** constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $h(a)=h(b)=c$ and again we may apply Rolle's Theorem. Note that $g'(x)=h'(x)$ and the rest of the proof of Lagrange's theorem remains the same.

The function
$$h(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\cdot x$$
has just that form with
$$c=-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} a+f(a)=\frac{bf(a)-af(b)}{b-a}.$$
In another way, this $h(x)$ is the function $g(x)$ where we *removed* all the additive constants.

Comment: I tried to arrive at that auxiliary function by some how relating the slope of function g(x) (obeys Rolle's theorem)to that of h(x) where h(x) is simply g(x) rotated by some degree theta. But it got quite messy.

Comment: @SoumyaPatel No rotation is involved here, just a vertical translation.

Comment: By rotation what i meant is if you took a graph like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAlQn-u1HtpLq1RnHyBs8tGTJjJ9AjVqwQdQ&usqp=CAU and then rotate it by some degrees it will turn out to be somehow like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCt_9dIdo1KyCWji7ovntpye7WvyhqiaNCyQ&usqp=CAU . And seeing that i concluded that i can relate the slope of g'(x)=m¹ and slope of h'(x)=m² by the angel between slopes formula.And use that relation to prove lagrange's theorem as we already know g'(c)=0 .

Comment: I understand, but pay attention to the fact that the rotated graph of a function is not always the graph of another function. I mean: over the same $x$ you could have more that one $y$.